# Calculate $ \lim_{n \to \infty }a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Given $c>0$, $ a_1=\frac{c}{2}$, $a_{n+1}=\frac{c}{2}+\frac{a_n^2}{2}$ $n=1,2,...$ Prove that$$ \lim_{n \to \infty }a_n=\begin{cases} 
      1-\sqrt{1-c} & 0<c \leq1 \\
      +\infty & c>1
   \end{cases}
$$
What if $-3\leq c<0$?
I'm wondering if there is clever ways to calculate the limit? As I think this can be done by showing the sequence is monotone and bounded/unbounded and then calculate the limit. For example, 
Here $a_{n+1}=\frac{c}{2}+\frac{a_n^2}{2}>\sqrt{ca_n^2}=\sqrt{c}a_n>a_n $ if $c>1$. So this case, I think $a_n$ is increasing and diverge. I'm wondering other methods of calculating the limit.

Comment: If $a_n\to x$, then 
$$x=\dfrac{c}{2}+\dfrac{x^2}{2},$$
this is equivalent to
$$x^2-2x+c=0.$$
Applying quadratic formula and reducing we get
$$x=1\pm\sqrt{1-c}.$$
If $c\leq1$, and by assumption $a_n\leq1,$ then $$a_{n+1}=\dfrac{c}{2}+\dfrac{a_n^2}{2}\leq\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}=1,$$
so by order limit properties $x\leq 1<1+\sqrt{1-c},$ hence $x=1-\sqrt{1-c}.$ This tells us for $c\leq1$ it is enough to show that $a_n$ converges.

Comment: and when $3<c<0$, then the sequence has two converging sub-sequences converging to different limit.